# Change DOM objects from PHP in different location

Tags: javascript, php, html

I like to have all my php code at the bottom of my html file.

I have a DOM object tag `<input id="name"/>` and I want to change the value attribute of that element to a value in php.

I am trying to avoid doing the following...

`<input id="name" value="<?php echo 'somevalue'; ?>" />`

And would rather set the value in separate php code down below. (kind of like javascript)

```
<input id="name"/>
<?php How do I set the input tag's value in php here?>
```

I would also like to avoid echoing out javascript to do the task....

So what I am saying is there anyway for php to go back after it has scripted out some html to go change what it has scripted out.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. PHP should process your request and prepare HTML to be displayed. What you want is possible with buffering your output to PHP variable and process it with [DOMDocument](http://php.net/DOMDocument), but I strongly recommend to change your approach to this.

Answer (score 1):

Once the document has been sent out, it is out of PHP's range, you will have to use Javascript, or you should've enclosed your whole HTML file in a PHP variable to access it with a DOM Parser.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not aware of HTML or the DOM when you are using `echo` or `?>direct output<?php`, it is just sending strings to the browser.

You could create a DOM object or similar representing your output page and manipulate that, but it doesn't make a lot of sense. Unlike in JS, where you are dynamically responding to events and manipulating something that's already on the screen, the output generated by PHP is a "one-shot" thing: once you've done preparing it, the browser renders it, once, and then you have no more control over it.

You need to instead be thinking in terms of *data* and *templates*: PHP code can prepare some data, into one or more variables, and then pass that data to a particular template, which goes through and renders content based on it. The distinction is that the template shouldn't make any decisions about objective truths, only about how you want things to be displayed.

There are various dedicated libraries for doing this, such as [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) and [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), or you can just `include` a PHP file which you have designated as your template.